# Improving MySQL performance on RDS by partitioning

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, partitioning, database-performance

I am trying to improve a performance of some large tables (can be millions of records) in a MySQL 8.0.20 DB on RDS.

Scaling up DB instance and IOPS is not the way to go, as it is very expensive (the DB is live 24/7).
Proper indexes (including composite ones) do already exist to improve the query performance.
The DB is mostly read-heavy, with occasional massive writes - when these writes happen, reads can be just as massive at the same time.

I thought about doing partitioning. Since MySQL doesn't support vertical partitioning, I considered doing horizontal partitioning - which should work very well for these large tables, as they contain activity records from dozens/hundreds of accounts, and storing each account's records in a separate partition makes a lot of sense to me.
But these tables do contain some constraints with foreign keys, which rules out using MySQL's horizontal partitioning : [Restrictions and Limitations on Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html)

> **Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables.**  Partitioned tables using the InnoDB storage engine do not support foreign keys. More specifically, this means that the following two statements are true:
>
> 1. No definition of an InnoDB table employing user-defined partitioning may contain foreign key references; no InnoDB table whose definition contains foreign key references may be partitioned.
> 2. No InnoDB table definition may contain a foreign key reference to a user-partitioned table; no InnoDB table with user-defined partitioning may contain columns referenced by foreign keys.

What are my options, other than doing "sharding" by using separate tables to store activity records on a per account basis? That would require a big code change to accommodate such tables. Hopefully there is a better way, that would only require changes in MySQL, and not the application code. If the code needs to be changed - the less the better :)

Comment: The general rules: Partitioning (vertical) will not help performance and may hurt.  Horizontal partitioning, also, has very few use cases that help performance.  Sharding seems excessive if you have only "millions" or rows.  Please provide more details on the data and the queries so we can give you more specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> storing each account's records in a separate partition makes a lot of sense to me

Instead, have the `PRIMARY KEY` *start* with `acct_id`.  This provides performance at least as good as `PARTITION BY acct_id`, saves disk space, and "clusters" an account's data together for "locality of reference".

> The DB is mostly read-heavy

Replicas allows 'infinite' scaling of reads.  But if you are not overloading the single machine now, there may be no need for this.

> with occasional massive writes

Let's discuss techniques to help with that.  Please explain what those writes entail -- hourly/daily/sporadic?  replace random rows / whole table / etc?  keyed off what?  Etc.

> Proper indexes (including composite ones) do already exist to improve the query performance.

Use the slowlog (with `long_query_time = 1` or lower) to verify.  Use `pt-query-digest` to find the top one or two queries.  Show them to us -- we can help you "think out of the box".

> read-heavy

Is the working set size less than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  That is, are you CPU-bound and not I/O-bound?

**More on PARTITION**

`PRIMARY KEY(acct_id, ..some other columns..)` orders the data primarily on acct_id and makes this efficient:  `WHERE acct_id=123 AND ...`.

`PARTITION BY .. (acct_id)` -- A `PARTITION` is implemented as a separate "table".  "Partition pruning" is the act of deciding which partition(s) are needed for the query.  So `WHERE acct_id=123 AND ...` will first do that pruning, then look for the row(s) in that "table" to handle the `AND ...`.  Hopefully, there is a good index (perhaps the `PRIMARY KEY`) to handle that part of the filtering.

The pruning is sort of takes the place of one level of BTree.  It is hard to predict which will be slower or faster.

Note that when partitioning by, say, acct_id, there is usually not efficient to *start* the index with that column.  (However, it would need to be later in the PK.)

**Big Deletes**

There are several ways to do a "big delete" while minimizing the impact on the system.  Partitioning by date is optimal but does not sound viable for your type of data.  Check out the others listed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Since you say that the deletion is usually less than 15%, the "copy over what needs to be *kept*" technique is not applicable either.

Comment: 1) Can you please explain why using account ID would boost performance same way as horizontal partitioning would?   2)The writes are triggered by events scheduled by customers - can happen as often as every 15-30 minutes, can be once a day/week. There are many different schedules per account.  When a schedule runs, many new records may be created, some records may be deleted, but usually no records are changed.  3) Can slow log be enabled on RDS? There is no access to the file system 4) I suspect the main issue is the reindexing of the entire table when new records are added

Comment: 3) There may be a UI way to turn it on and down the log.  Do check `long_query_time`.

Comment: 4) There is essentially no reason to ever reindex an entire table after some INSERTs.  If, on the other hand, you are rebuilding the table from scratch, please provide more details.  (INSERTed rows are automatically and 'immediately' added to each index.)

Comment: 1) I added "More on PARTITION".

Comment: 2) How many rows in a typical account before the 'event'?  How many after?  (I am fishing for whether the change is: total replacement / large change / small change.  I might might have different recommendations depending on that.  (Meanwhile, thinks for providing the "frequency".)

Comment: Thank you for the "More on PARTITION" explanation! As for the amount of records added  and/or deleted during a scheduled event, usually less than 2-3% of records are added, and up to 10-20% can be deleted. Frequency of the events is totally up to the customer, an can range from 15 minutes to once a week. I have found a way to enable slow log in RDS using "Parameter group", but I will have to find a customer who will agree to do this on their server, since mine doesn't have enough data

Comment: I think that the deletion events are the ones more critical, since they affect much more rows each time (they run less frequently than events that add rows), and they are of course more query-heavy than the addition events - need to find the exact rows to delete.

Comment: @Gromit - I added a "Big Deletes" section.

Comment: Thank you! The actual problem turned out to be not the MySQL part, but what our code was doing with the retrieved information - I couldn't have figured this out without your and Bill's help!

Answer (score 1):

Before sharding or partitioning, first analyze your queries to make sure they are as optimized as you can make them. This usually means designing indexes specifically to support the queries you run. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU)).

Partitioning isn't as much a solution as people think. It has many restrictions, including the foreign key issue you found. Besides that, it only improves queries that can take advantage of partition pruning.

Also, I've done a lot of benchmarking of Amazon RDS for my current job and also a previous job. RDS is slow. It's really slow. It uses remote EBS storage, so it's bound to incur overhead for every read from storage or write to storage. RDS is just not suitable for any application that needs high performance.

Amazon Aurora is significantly better on latency and throughput. But it's also very expensive. The more you use it, the more you use I/O requests, and they charge extra for that. For a busy app, you end up spending as much as you did for RDS with high provisioned IOPS.

The only way I found to get high performance in the cloud is to forget about managed databases like RDS and Aurora, and instead install and run your own instance of MySQL on an ec2 instance with locally-attached NVMe storage. This means the **i3** family of ec2 instances. But local storage is ephemeral instance storage, so if the instance restarts, you lose your data. So you must add one or more replicas and have a failover plan.

If you need an OLTP database in the cloud, and you also need top-tier performance, you either have to spend $$$ for a managed database, or else you need to hire full-time DevOps and DBA staff to run it.

Sorry to give you the bad news, but the [TANSTAAFL adage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) remains true.

Comment: I watched the  excellent "How to Design Indexes, Really" video, as you have recommended in my other question on SO. It's a fantastic introduction to indexes for a newbie like me.  Can you please share some benchmarks of RDS vs local MySQL? We do have some customers using RDS and some local MySQL (running on an AWS instance, so it's also using EBS)

Comment: Sorry, the results of the benchmarks belong to my employer, so I can't share them.

Comment: Would you say that there is no advantage to using RDS or MySQL on an AWS instance, if both of them use the same EBS storage type, since EBS latency will be the main limiting factor in performance?

Comment: Yes, for the same reason that NFS is a terrible idea for database storage in non-cloud datacenter deployments. Remote storage has too much latency. It's adequate if you're only hosting the database for your amateur sourdough breadmaking blog, but if you need high performance, it's no good.